# How can I get facebook page id from custom fan page

Tags: facebook

I have a fan page https://www.facebook.com/pages/Hiruscar-Kids-HK/1495541247325600, how can I know its page id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID is in the URL: `1495541247325600`

If you already set a Vanity-URL, you can get it like this: `https://graph.facebook.com/vanity-url`

Same call with the ID: https://graph.facebook.com/1495541247325600

Comment: Can I create an app and check third party's fan page whether the facebook user has liked the fan page?

Comment: you would need the "user_likes" permission for that, but facebook does not approve this just for checking if someone likes a page.